# Power BI DAX - Dynamically Calculate Distinct Count of Patients with Most Recent Value Less Than 9

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of a1C values structured in this way:

```
patientID    Result_Date    Value

A            1/1/2021         5

B            3/3/2021         9

C            5/5/2021         4

A            3/1/2021         9

B            6/1/2021         13

A            7/1/2021         4

C            4/8/2022         12
```

etc...

I need to create a DAX measure that will dynamically calculate the distinct count of patients who have a value less than 9 as their last value as well as the distinct count of all patients in the population from the past 12 months of whatever date range is filtered. This is so I can calculate % a1c < 9. I have a calendar table in this data model so the idea is that as a user selects a fiscal month, the measure would dynamically calculate the % of distinct patients with an a1C less than 9 as their latest value over the past 12 months. I cannot share the actual dataset per HIPAA

Here are a few examples of the work I tried to do just to get a table of patients with their most recent date and most recent value as I figure that is the first step. I have been unsuccessful. Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
VAR summaryTable = 
    VAR patientID = VALUES(A1c[patientID])
    VAR results = FILTER(A1c, A1c[patientID] = patientID)
    VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE( MAX(A1c[Result_Date]), results)
 RETURN
 CALCULATETABLE(A1c, FILTER(results, A1c[Result_Date] = MaxDate)

/*ADDCOLUMNS(SUMMARIZE(A1c, A1c[patientID], "ValueDate", MAX(A1c[Result_Date]))
  //  , "LastValue", LOOKUPVALUE(A1c[Value_Formatted], A1c[Result_Date], FORMAT("ValueDate", "MM/DD/YYYY"), A1c[patientID], "patientID"))
// does not run due to formatting of columns; attempted to format but still doesn't work

//ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(A1c[patientID]), "ValueDate", MAX(A1c[Result_Date]))
/*    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( A1c[patientID] ),
        "@outer val",
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                TOPN ( 1, 'A1c', MAX(A1c[Result_Date]) ),
                "@val", 'A1c'[Value_Formatted]
                )) */)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lessThanNine =    

VAR patientlastDates=
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            VALUES(tbl[patientID])
            ,"lastdate",LASTDATE(tbl[Result_Date])
        )
VAR patientLastValue =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            patientlastDates
            ,"lastValue",   VAR currentP=[patientID]
                            VAR currentD=[lastdate]
                            RETURN 
                                CALCULATE(
                                    MAX(tbl[Value])
                                    ,tbl[patientID]=currentP
                                    ,tbl[Result_Date]=currentD
                            )
        )
VAR filtered=
            FILTER(
        patientLastValue
        ,[lastValue]<9
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS(filtered)
```

Distinct count as below:

```
patientsWithinTimeFrame=
IF(
    ISFILTERED('tbl'[Result_Date])
    ,COUNTROWS(VALUES('tbl'[patientID]))
    ,COUNTROWS(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES('tbl'[patientID])
            ,DATESINPERIOD(
                'tbl'[Result_Date]
                ,MAX('tbl'[Result_Date])
                ,-1
                ,year
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: This looks great! Seems to be giving the right results of the time period that is filtered. Only adjustment now is to get the 12 months rolling. I'm going to do some further testing to get it to give a 12 month look back and will follow back up. Thanks again!